# How to change the value of array of items in a state in ReactJS?

Tags: reactjs

My state values are as follows:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      list: [
        { id: '1', age: 42 },
        { id: '2', age: 33 },
        { id: '3', age: 68 },
      ],
    };
}
```

And my handle function is

```
handle() {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
        list: {
            ...prevState.list,
            [prevState.list[1]]: {
                ...prevState.list[1],
                age: 40
            }
        }
    }))
}
```

What I want here is to change the `age` of second row from `33` to `40`, but my code is wrong. Can anyone suggest a correct way?

Required answer:

```
list: [
    { id: '1', age: 42 },
    { id: '2', age: 40 },
    { id: '3', age: 68 },
  ],
```

Comment: Your new state doesn't have the same *shape* as the old one, you're changing `this.state.list` from an array to an object. Try `{ list: prevState.list.map(...) }`.

Comment: You would need to check which row you want to change and pass that value to the handleFunction.
A simple approach could be:
``list.map(each=>{
each.id==2?each.age=40:null
})``

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple and efficient of doing this can be changing the array first by saving it into another variable. Then use that variable to set the state directly.
You can do it like this:

```
handle(){
  let lists = [...this.state.lists];
  lists[1].age = 40;
  this.setState({lists});
}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Consider this:

```
handle() {
  const { state: { list } } = this;
  const newList = [...list]
  newList[1].age = 40;
    this.setState({ list: newList })
}
```

The ES6 clone by destruct for Arrays have no side effects!

Comment: there should be no `const` before that line. can you copy the answer as it is?